# css animation transformation center by screen center

Tags: css, animation, transform

How to make a body transformation has occurred relative to the center of the screen, not the center of the page along the Y-axis ?

link to the code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPqKXe
it is more text for publish1 it is more text for publish2

```css
  .blok {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #92FF00;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size:36px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 85px 0 35px 0 ; 
}
 
body {
 transform: perspective( 200px );
   
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
 -webkit-animation: rotateRightSideFirst 5s forwards ease-in;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
 -moz-animation: rotateRightSideFirst 5s forwards ease-in;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 animation: rotateRightSideFirst 5s forwards ease-in;
  
}


@-webkit-keyframes rotateRightSideFirst {
 50% { -webkit-transform: translateZ(-700px) ; 
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px); }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotateRightSideFirst {
 50% { -moz-transform: translateZ(-700px) ; -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateZ(-200px); }
}

@keyframes rotateRightSideFirst {
 50% { transform: translateZ(-700px) ; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
 100% { transform: translateZ(-200px); }
}
```

```html
  <div class="blok">1</div>
  <div class="blok">2</div>
  <div class="blok">3</div>
  <div class="blok">4</div>
  <div class="blok">5</div>
  <div class="blok">6</div>
  <div class="blok">7</div>
  <div class="blok">8</div>
  <div class="blok">9</div>
  <div class="blok">10</div>
  <div class="blok">11</div>
  <div class="blok">12</div>
  <div class="blok">13</div>
  <div class="blok">14</div>
  <div class="blok">15</div>
  <div class="blok">16</div>
  <div class="blok">17</div>
  <div class="blok">18</div>
```

Comment: div 1,2,3 mimic section of the website - the content.

Comment: Let's say we scroll the website up to section number 13. Need to relative to the current section 13 was the distance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you would like to have a div wrapper thats fixed on screen. Following css rule would help you:

```
.fixedWrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%
}
```

And

```
<div class="fixedWrapper">
... your html content...
</div>
```

If you'd like to have it in center of page (along the header and footer) you would create a wrapper and position it absolute with left & top 50% and with transform: translate(-50%, -50%) as well.

Answer (score 0):

If `.blok` haa a width set you can use `margin: 0 auto;`.

Otherwise:

```
.blok {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: div 1,2,3 mimic section of the website - the content. I did not understand a bit what do you suggest? if you wrap all sections in a div#iamcentered, it leads to the scroll lock and compression in the horizontal direction.

Comment: Unfortunately, no effect.tion.